# value session is not a member of Unit

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

```
  def getSessionDetails(
      sessionId: String,
      expectedStatus: String = "success"
  ) = {
    exec(
      http("/cap/getSessionDetails")
        .get("/cap/getSessionDetails.do")
        .queryParam("sessionID", sessionId)
        .check(status.in(200))
        .check(jsonPath("$.status").is(expectedStatus))
        .check(
          jsonPath("$.data.sessionTimes[0].enrollmentStatus").find
            .saveAs("enrollmentStatus")
        )
        .check(
          jsonPath("$.data.sessionTimes[0].id").find.saveAs("sessionTimeID")
        )
    ).exec { session => println(session) session }

  }
```

I am trying to get values to print for debugging, but no matter where I put the println line of code in this block, I get some kind of error. Right now as it is, I get "value session is not a member of Unit". Looking at other examples, I can't tell where mine is different.

Comment: Add a semicolon `;` after the `println()`.

Comment: @jwvh That worked. And when I look at my resources, they have a semi-colon too which I was using to begin with. But it wasn't working so that was one of the things I tried changing. I'm not sure why it works with it now, but thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In your line `.exec { session => println(session) session }`, you should insert a semicolon or a line break after `println(session)`.

Otherwise, you are trying to call `session` on the return value of `println(..)`, which is of type `Unit`. However, Unit (something like 'void' in Java), does not have such a member.

How are you calling it? Postfix notation in scala allows you to call methods without parameters by writing `object method` instead of `object.method()` (read more under https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html).